# Need to construct a URL to test localhost and parameters - Visual Studio Code and Python

Tags: python, json, parameter-passing, urlencode, azure-http-trigger

EDIT 12.1 16:21 EST:
SO I narrowed it down.  This works (python3):

```
ptc = req.params.get('name')
    assets = req.params.get('assets')
    if not ptc:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
            
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            ptc = req_body.get('name')
            assets = req_body.get('assets')
            
            
    if ptc:
        
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello boogerface, {ptc}, {assets}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

And when I strip out the conditionals and try except statements to make it look like this (python3):

```
ptc = req.params.get('name')
assets = req.params.get('assets')
req_body = req.get_json()
ptc = req_body.get('name')
assets = req_body.get('assets')  
return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {ptc}, {assets}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
```

It fails.  HTTP 500 in the browser and:

> HTTP request does not contain valid JSON data

as the error code

**Can someone tell me why the second set doesn't work?**  Because it's just the code without the if/thens and try excepts.  I just didn't think it would have made too much of a difference.  I fully expect it to work.  And when I mean work, this shows up in the browser window:

[image: Success]

END EDIT

I created an httptrigger inside Visual Studio Code (VSC) written in Python.  I'm trying to reconstruct the URL (NOT in the code, **just to test** the call through the browser using the URL).

*What I've done so far:*
When I execute the function from within VSC and pass the JSON string as a JSON string (in the execution window) -  e.g. {"var1":"value1","var2":"value2"}  for ANY number of parameters that match the variables in my code, it runs successfully.

The browser is a different story.

When I have ONE parameter to pass in the URL, for example (following is NOT an actual URL):

> http://localhosturl/thisapi?var1=OHMYGOSH

**without quotes and without any encoding**, the HttpResponse is just fine. It gives me the parameter's value in the browser.  **Returning the value to the browser at this juncture is simply a debug step for me.**

Now when I have **MORE than one value in the URL**, for example:

> http://localhosturl/thisapi?var1=OHMYGOSH&var2=THISISCRAZY

I receive a HTTP ERROR 500 in the browser for the local host. In the terminal I receive the error explanation as:

> HTTP request does not contain valid JSON data

**How does a JSON string look like in a parameterized URL? is my ultimate question.** I've looked everywhere. I've tried or looked into:

- URL encoding (?"URL encoded string")
- Base64 encoding (?"Base64encoded string")
- Also ?req="URLorBase64encodedstring" since req is the parameter it is being passed into
- direct - as in sample URL above
- solutions providing programmatically creating it INSIDE the code (which is what I DON'T want to do)

**I just want to construct one URL with multiple values being passed to make the API call work in a browser for now.**

Why?  Because when I deploy it to the server, **I want another script to construct a URL** to make the call so I can receive the values after a calculation.  So I need to know what that final URL looks like that I can send it.

Again, I've searched stackoverflow and so many other sites.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: what is `httptrigger` ? How it works? Do you have documentation for this? Maybe it needs something different. Usually `JSON` is send in request's body, not in url.

Comment: @furas httptrigger is an event used when calling an API's URL.  So basically, I want to send values to the API from a webpage and have it do a calculation and return several values to print to the webpage.  For THAT to happen, I have to construct the URL from the script.  Which is why I am checking for it in the localhost URL to see what that will look like so I can properly construct it.  

When I pass the JSON in Visual Studio code, works just fine.  Need to construct the URL to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

When creating an Azure httpTrigger in Visual Studio Code, you will be given an if (if not) then/try except structure that works just fine as a default.  I have found that if you remove the conditional statement and try to run it outside of it, it doesn't seem to work.

So instead of trying to solve this programmatically, I went ahead and accepted the structure as it was and it works just fine.  DO NOTE:  When testing inside Visual Studio Code, you will be passing JSON into the test field, but when passing it in a browser URL to test locally, the parameters pass as literal so you will have to use the req.params.get when assigning variables instead of dumping it with json.dumps().  You probably will have to change the conditionals to test for JSON format upon entry but that will depend on your function's use cases.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).